# functional dependencies in databases

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

I'm really confused at determine functional dependencies and need to confirm that I have all my dependencies list. I have a table.

[image]

From the following table, i found:

[image]

My question here is that, did i correctly list all of possible functional dependencies here? Also (If I'm right), i see that `model --> make`, Do i still need to `model, color --> make`, etc..Also since `make, msrp --> model, year` , do I still need `model, year --> make, msrp` in the list?

Comment: A great example of why you *cannot* sensibly derive FDs from data alone. Is the database supposed to implement the dependency that Make and Color determine Model? Highly unlikely.

Comment: Functional Dependenices are a feature of the subject matter that the database is intended to reflect.  You discover FDs by analyzing the subject.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. PS What does that table value have to do with the question? Do you want exactly the FDs that hold *in this value* or in a variable that could hold this value or what--exactly? What were you supposed to return? A closure? A cover? A canonical/irreducible/minimal cover? You comment re that but--Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Functional dependencies hold for all time.**

When you try to derive FDs from data, you're liable to derive FDs that hold only by coincidence. The FD `make, color -> model` means "When I see a Honda that's red, I know it's an Accord." As far as the data you're given is concerned, that's true. But you and I know that, if we wait for more data, we're certain to find a red Honda Civic. The FD `make, color -> model` holds for this sample data, but it doesn't hold for all time.

To determine whether you've found all the FDs based on sample data, you have to test every possible combination of attributes. (Or, better yet, write a program to do it.)  I didn't try to find all of them. You seem to be on the right track.

> Also (If I'm right), i see that model --> make, Do i still need to
>   model, color --> make, etc.

If you're doing this for school, your professor probably wants to see a) all the possible FDs (so, include `model, color --> make`) and b) all the FDs after you've removed the reducible ones (so, remove `model, color --> make`).

> Also since make, msrp --> model, year , do I still need model, year
>   --> make, msrp in the list?

Yes. Normalization through BCNF depends on determing a) all the candidate keys, and b) all the prime and nonprime attributes. (A prime attribute is an attribute that's part of *any* candidate key.) The set of FDs `{AB->CD}` gives you one candidate key, `AB`, and two nonprime attributes, `C, D`. The set of FDs `{AB->CD, CD->AB}` gives you *two* candidate keys and zero nonprime attributes.

Comment: We are asked to remove trivial or implied dependencies and i believe there are none, am i correct?

Comment: You don't list any trivial FDs. But  `model, color -> make` is implied, because `model -> make`.

Comment: Great that also answer the question i asked above that i dont need to list model,color --> make then. Thanks alot

Comment: @ln206 "Remove implied dependencies" is not what is wanted. FDs are implied by sets of FDs & when there is more than one minimal/irreducible cover the FDs unique to a cover are implied by every other cover so you would return none of them. You mean that you want a set of FDs that implies all others in the table but with no member implied by the set of the other members--a minimal/irreducible cover! Also, adding that you don't want trivial FDs is redundant since each is implied by every FD set (whether or not any FDs in it hold).